# Como adiantar duas casas decimais em php ou javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte
tenho o valor 1000000
e tenho que formatar ele assim 10.000,00
Porque o valor vem pra mim já formatado e não consigo usar o between (mysql) para buscar um valor então eu faço :

```
$preco = $row->preco;
$newpreco = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$preco);
```

Assim obtendo o valor sem letras e sem pontuação
deste modo consigo filtrar usando

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE preco BETWEEN '2000000' AND '5000000';
```

obs: 2000000 é referente a 20.000,00

porem quando retorno esse valor precisava formatar ele com as pontuações novamente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu sugiro que você use o `number_format`, veja a documentação [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php)

```
$preco = number_format ($row->preco, 2, ',' ,'.');
```

Aqui, se você passa 10000, ele retorna 10.000,00. Eu no seu lugar, faria duas funções auxiliares, uma que já faz o que você faz e outra com o código acima para o retorno

Comment: Obrigado consegui fazer isso, usando o valor recebido dividido por 100 e usei o number_format do jeito que você mostrou deu certo obrigado.

Comment: Que bom amigo, é uma boa